# AWS Lambda - Send URL as GET Parameter from PHP to Java Lambda function

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a AWS lambda function that takes 5 parameters. One of the parameter is a Url, that is passed from PHP backend, as a get parameter. The url is encoded while passing, and the parameters are passed as a JSONObject. Please note, i am using JSONObject from amazonaws sdk (com.amazonaws.util.json).

The input object is converted to a JSONObject in the lambda function, before getting the values from it. The problem comes when converting to input to Json, because of the url. If i pass a string in place of url, the lambda works just fine.

Here is the relevant code and outputs:

```
@Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {

        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

        if (DEBUG)
            logger.log("Starting LambdaFunction");

        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

        try {

            if (DEBUG)
                logger.log("Input: " + input.toString());

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(input.toString());//Problem here

            if (DEBUG)
                logger.log("Object: " + object.toString());

            String name = object.getString("name");
            String message = object.getString("message");
            String survey_url = object.getString("url");
            String user_id = object.getString("user_id");
            String number = object.getString("number");

            if (DEBUG) {
                logger.log("Name: " + name);
                logger.log("Message: " + message);
                logger.log("Survey Url: " + survey_url);
                logger.log("User ID: " + user_id);
                logger.log("Number: " + number);
            }

            // Other functionality
        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            logger.log("JSONException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TwilioRestException e) {
            logger.log("TwilioRestException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "End of SendSMSLambdaFunction";
    }
```

call from php -> Lambda ::: `https://xxx.amazonaws.com/prod/sendsmsapiresource?name=test&number=9618143233&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&message=testmesage&user_id=1`

output from cloudwatch for Lambda :::

```
Input: {name=test, number=9618143233, message=test, url=http://www.example.com, user_id=1}
JSONException
com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 55 [character 56 line 1]
```

How can i pass url as get parameter to lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved, when i added ' ' for the url, in the lambda call from php. So now invoke call looks like, `https://xxx.amazonaws.com/prod/sendsmsapiresource?name=test&number=9618143233&url=%27http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%27&message=testmesage&user_id=1` and my input to lambda comes as `Input: {name=test, number=9618143233, message=test, url='http://www.example.com', user_id=1}`